# Can I simplify my C code for checking if the pin is set?

Tags: avr, atmega

The first pin of PortD is HIGH at the beginning. When the first 4 pins of PortA are HIGH, set the second pin of PORTD HIGH, and the first LOW.

```
 `PORTD=0b00000001;
      
      if (PINA & (1<<0))
      {
          if (PINA &(1<<1))
          {
              if(PINA &(1<<2))
              {
                  if(PINA &(1<<3))
                  {
                      PORTD=0b00000001;
                  }
              }
          }
      }`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test the 4 lower pins of port A simultaneously with `(PINA & 0x0f) == 0x0f`.
Then you can set the lower 2 bits of PORT D to 01 using `PORTD = (PORTD & ~3) | 2;` Thus the code becomes

```
if((PINA & 0b00001111) == 0b00001111){
    PORTD = (PORTD & 0b11111100) | 0b00000010;
}
```

or equally

```
if((PINA & 0x0f) == 0x0f){
    PORTD = (PORTD & ~3) | 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```c
//..intialization code...
PORTD=0b00000001; // initialize of port D
while(true){
  //... your code body...
  if((PINA & 0x0f) == 0x0f){ // if first 4 bit are high
      PORTD |=(1<<PD1); //set pd1 to high
      PORTD &=~(1<<PD0); // set pd0 to low
  }
  else{
      // here put what you like to do if the 4 bit not High
      // if there is nothing to do delete the else

  }
  //... your code body...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an other solution would be to use a switch e.g:

```c
DDRD = (1<<PIND1) | (1<<PIND0);

switch ((PINA & 0x0F))
{
    case 0x0F:
      PORTD = (1<<PIND1);
      break;
    default:
      PORTD = (1<<PIND0);
      break;
}
```